# F12 Converts Object to Array

Tags: jquery, json, angularjs, requirejs

I have a js file routeLoader.js

```
var routeLoader = {
    routeData: {},

    myLoader: function () {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:61362/api/menu/getmenus/emptyString',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                routeLoader.routeData = data;
                return data;
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

and in my adminModule.js file I have the following:

```
var dependencies = ['scripts/Angular/angular-route', 'utils/routeResolver'];
define(dependencies, function (ngRoute, Resolver) {
    'use strict';
    var adminModule = angular.module('app.adminModule', ['ngRoute', 'routeResolverServices']);
    adminModule.config(['$routeProvider', 'routeResolverProvider', '$controllerProvider', '$provide',
        function ($routeProvider, routeResolverProvider, $constrollerProvider, $provide) {
            adminModule.lazyRegister = {
                controller: $constrollerProvider.register,
                factory: $provide.factory
            };

            var rpRoute = routeResolverProvider.route;
            try {
                routeLoader.routeData.forEach(function (route) {
                    $routeProvider
                    .when(route.menuName, rpRoute.resolve(route.viewDirectory, route.controllerDirectory, route.baseName, route.path))
                });
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e.message);
            }
        }
    ]);
    return adminModule;
});
```

the routeLoader.routeData contains an array of JSON data, which is the desired results, when running the F12 Dev Tools in both Chrome and IE. Not running the F12 Dev Tools the routeLoader.routeData is simply an Object and the routeLoader.routeData.forEach fails since it does not contain any JSON data. I have no idea what is going on; any assistance would be appreciated.

btw: the routeLoader.js is loaded after the jquery.js file and just before the Angular.js file in my index.html page.

Comment: ajax likely not completed when angular starts bootstrapping

Comment: Was able to make it work by removing the .success / .error and replacing it with:

Comment: Was able to make it work by replacing the ajax call with
             
    var routeLoader = {routeData: {}, myLoader: function(){return $.ajax({ url: 'aURL', type: 'GET', dataType:'json'}).promise();}};   

Thanks for everyone looking at this and assisting.